# Spring Integration 2 - Splitter only returns the first element

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration 2. I have the following scenario. A 'MassMessageObject' which is made up of a body field and a list of recipients. I am implementing a splitter to create a 'BasicMessageObject' for every recipient in the list. The problem is that only the first message is received by the output channel of the splitter. Eg:

MassMessageObject> [body: Hello, recipients{A,B}]
Is creating a List of BasicMessageObject
{[body: Hello, recipient: A], [body: Hello, recipient: B]}.

The endpoint connected to the out put channel is receiving '[body: Hello, recipient: A]' but not '[body: Hello, recipient: B]'.

The following is my application context:

```
<int:splitter input-channel="mass_receiving_channel"
                  output-channel="receiving_channel"                  
                  method="splitMessages"
                  ref="massMessageSplitter"/>

<!-- Main Chain. The one that will lead to the messageTypeRouter -->
<int:chain input-channel="receiving_channel" output-channel="sms_channel">
        <int:service-activator ref="saveMessageToDB" method="saveMessageToDB"/>
        <int:gateway request-channel="message_type_router_channel"/>
</int:chain>
```

The following is the splitter ...

```
public List<BasicMessageObject> splitMessages(final GenericMessage message) {
        List<BasicMessageObject> messages = new ArrayList<BasicMessageObject>();
        // DOING STUFF HERE 
        return messages;
    }
}





[springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener:234] - converted JMS Message [ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 6, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:PC-CMICALLEF-61953-1335249128607-0:0:1:2:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:PC-CMICALLEF-61953-1335249128607-0:0:1:2, destination = queue://mass_messaging_queue, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1335249128840, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1335249128841, brokerOutTime = 1335249128842, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@39673d71, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false}] to integration Message payload [com.connexo.icubeplus3.dispatcher.connector.messageobjects.SmsMassMessageObject@28f2e328]
[springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel:224] - preSend on channel 'mass_receiving_channel', message: [Payload=com.connexo.icubeplus3.dispatcher.connector.messageobjects.SmsMassMessageObject@28f2e328][Headers={timestamp=1335249128882, id=fb9904da-f5b1-49e0-af25-6711015f1365, jms_redelivered=false, jms_messageId=ID:PC-CMICALLEF-61953-1335249128607-0:0:1:2:1}]
[springframework.integration.splitter.MethodInvokingSplitter:72] - org.springframework.integration.splitter.MethodInvokingSplitter@56de9984 received message: [Payload=com.connexo.icubeplus3.dispatcher.connector.messageobjects.SmsMassMessageObject@28f2e328][Headers={timestamp=1335249128882, id=fb9904da-f5b1-49e0-af25-6711015f1365, jms_redelivered=false, jms_messageId=ID:PC-CMICALLEF-61953-1335249128607-0:0:1:2:1}]
[springframework.integration.splitter.MethodInvokingSplitter:157] - handler 'org.springframework.integration.splitter.MethodInvokingSplitter@56de9984' sending reply Message: [Payload=[SMS] [sender: icube+] [destination: +35611111111] [messageIdentifier: 1234] [clientId: 1]][Headers={timestamp=1335249137537, id=566d7d54-f4cc-4896-8d39-d95636c20a57, correlationId=fb9904da-f5b1-49e0-af25-6711015f1365, jms_redelivered=false, sequenceSize=4, sequenceNumber=1, jms_messageId=ID:PC-CMICALLEF-61953-1335249128607-0:0:1:2:1}]
[springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel:224] - preSend on channel 'receiving_channel', message: [Payload=[SMS] [sender: icube+] [destination: +35611111111] [messageIdentifier: 1234] clientId: 1]][Headers={timestamp=1335249137537, id=566d7d54-f4cc-4896-8d39-d95636c20a57, correlationId=fb9904da-f5b1-49e0-af25-6711015f1365, jms_redelivered=false, sequenceSize=4, sequenceNumber=1, jms_messageId=ID:PC-CMICALLEF-61953-1335249128607-0:0:1:2:1}]
[springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain:72] - org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0 received message: [Payload=[SMS] [sender: icube+] [destination: +35611111111] [messageIdentifier: 1234] [clientId: 1]][Headers={timestamp=1335249137537, id=566d7d54-f4cc-4896-8d39-d95636c20a57, correlationId=fb9904da-f5b1-49e0-af25-6711015f1365, jms_redelivered=false, sequenceSize=4, sequenceNumber=1, jms_messageId=ID:PC-CMICALLEF-61953-1335249128607-0:0:1:2:1}]
[springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler:72] - ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@27b71c12] received message: [Payload=[SMS] [sender: icube+] [destination: +35611111111] [messageIdentifier: 1234] [clientId: 1]][Headers={timestamp=1335249137537, id=566d7d54-f4cc-4896-8d39-d95636c20a57, correlationId=fb9904da-f5b1-49e0-af25-6711015f1365, jms_redelivered=false, sequenceSize=4, sequenceNumber=1, jms_messageId=ID:PC-CMICALLEF-61953-1335249128607-0:0:1:2:1}] ....
```

Comment: I suggest you run with logger for org.springframework.integration set to DEBUG. You should be able to trace the messages through and figure out what's happending. If not, post the log here.

With this configuration, the second message won't be sent until the first one has completed. If you want them to run on separate threads, you'll need an async handoff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gary ... funny thing is that I just completed a tiny POC using splitters and all and guess what. It works well. So it must be some wrong conifg. I will take your suggestion and increase logging to DEBUG. cheers.

Comment: Just for the record I found out that attaching the output-channel to an activation service instead of a chain does the trick. Also, I have debugged in the spring integration code and found out that in AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult, the loop is quitted after the first iteration.

Comment: had the same problem, similarly as you describe in above comment I was missing reply-channel in my outbound-gateway after splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Adding a task executor to the outgoing channel of the splitter enables Spring to deliver all messages coming from the splitter:

```
<splitter input-channel="incoming-splitter" output-channel="outgoing-splitter"/>

<channel id="outgoing-splitter">
  <dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</channel>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
  <!-- Use 1 for sequential processing -->
  <property name="corePoolSize" value="1"/>
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1"/>
  <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="Splitter Message Handler "/>
  <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
</bean>
```